# Java network metric

Tags: java, networking

I try to check the IP of a hostname.

I have two network devices,

1. "A" has metric 1 168.172.1.54
2. "B" has metric 2 168.172.1.55

My hostname is `develop`.

I have a Webserver listening at 168.172.1.55 only. (Metric 2)

How to specify to use metric 2 using the hostname but not the IP-Address?

Comment: Too broad? How to be more specific?

Comment: Where does Java enter the equation exactly?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues In my case in the `JAVA_OPTS` as part of the `-Djboss.bind.address=develop` value.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two levels:

- The DNS level resolves hostnames to IP addresses, using a local resolver library that talks to local or remote DNS servers, caches and / or local sources such as "/etc/hosts".
- The routing level chooses between two or more network routes to use for a given IP address based on a metric.

What you appears to be trying to do is to have DNS resolution be influenced by routing metrics.   This doesn't really make sense to me.  This is not how DNS and routing metrics are supposed to be used.

IMO, the "makes sense" ways to do this are:

- Use IP addresses rather than hostnames (locally) to connect to your webserver.  The Java networking APIs allow you to do this with (typically<sup>1</sup>) zero code change.
- Use different DNS names for the two IP addresses.  For example, you could add a local DNS entry for one or other of the devices in your "hosts" file.   Or you could add entries in your local DNS server ... or your DNS provider.

Note that this is not really a Java question, since the mechanisms and the solutions won't be implemented in your Java application, and apply equally to other programming languages.

---

Actually, based on your comments on another Answer, I suspect that *part* of your problem may be routing.

Your Question seems to be saying that you have a system with two devices (NICs) and two different IP addresses, on two different networks (A and B).

Then you say in a comment that you cannot ping the IP on network B because its IP is not "available" on network A.

So here's the thing.  If you are on network A and you need to talk to the service which is listening on a port on an IP on network B, and packets are not routed from A to B, then that won't work.  If the packets are not routed, then it doesn't matter whether you refer to the server by its correct IP address or by a hostname.

On the other hand, if you are trying to ping a host that is on networks A and B ... from itself ... that should just work.  Unless something is really messed up with your network (or virtual network) configs, a host should be able to talk to all of its own IP addresses.

I suppose it is possible that your firewall is blocking the ping ... rather than a routing problem.   But that is also a misconfiguration, IMO.

---

<sup>1 ... unless your codebase has been implemented to explicitly exclude hostnames with IP address syntax.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use hostname instead of ip，you must have mechanism to resolve hostname to ip address.The method I first thought of is to modify the `hosts` file.

I implemented it as follows：

First,modify the `hosts` file,add the follow line to your `hosts` file tail.

```
168.172.1.55 develop
```

Second,start server and bind to `168.172.1.55` use name `develop`.I use vertx to simulate this:

```
NetServer server = Vertx.vertx().createNetServer();
server.connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(NetSocket netSocket) {
        System.out.println(netSocket.isSsl());
    }
});
server.listen(9091,"develop");
```

Ps: if you want use `name` in your system,name server might be a better choice，like DNS，Zookeeper，etcd and so on.

Comment: Name server should be a better choice only if, 1. it is a test simulating the production environment, 2. it is going to handle lots of requests either locally or in devlopment environment. Here, _hosts_ file seems a better choice.

Comment: The reason is they would take some additional configuration and time, see https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network

Comment: Cant ping my own hostname because the ip `168.172.1.55` is unavailable in network A.